# momentJs diff giving me wrong date but right time

Tags: javascript, momentjs

So i used [momentjs](https://momentjs.com/docs/) to change the format of my **date/time** and get the **difference**, so my problem is that its giving me the right diff time but wrong date ? the totalHrs is giving me a date of `01/01/1970 06:10:00`

**value of no and then is in the comment**

```
var now = moment(vm.userApproved.timeOut).format('MM/DD/YYYY HH:mm:ss'); // "2017-11-27T06:35:00.000Z"
var then = moment(vm.userApproved.timeIn).format('MM/DD/YYYY HH:mm:ss'); // "2017-11-27T00:25:00.000Z"
```

**totalHrs**

```
var totalHrs = moment.utc(moment(now).diff(moment(then))).format('MM/DD/YYYY HH:mm:ss'); // "01/01/1970 06:10:00"
```

The Result i want is to be the date today example result: **"11/27/2017 06:10:00""**

Thanks, Any Suggestion's are welcomed.

Comment: why would you think that the difference between two times would result in a meaningful Date?

Comment: try `var totalHrs = moment(vm.userApproved.timeIn).format('MM/DD/YYYY ') + moment.utc(moment(now).diff(moment(then))).format('HH:mm:ss');`